# Pasar el dato de una fila seleccionada de una base de datos de MySQL a otra tabla en Netbeans con JFrame

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing

Deseo insertar y a su vez borrar una fila seleccionada de una tabla a otra tabla en otro JFrame, considerando que los datos de la primer tabla son extraídos de una base de datos de MySQL.
Ya manda a llamar los datos, pero al momento de seleccionar una fila, debería de mandarla a otra tabla.

Muestra los datos en la primera tabla y de igual forma ya selecciona la fila, pero no las envía a la otra tabla.

```java
private void jt1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
                          
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {

        Conexion objConn = new Conexion();
        Connection conn = objConn.getConection();

        int Fila = jt1.getSelectedRow();
        String id_act = jt1.getValueAt(Fila, 0).toString();

        ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id_act, nombre_actividad, situacion FROM actividades, estado ");
        //ps.setString(1, id_act);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        int resp = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Realizar la actividad " + id_act);
        if (JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == resp){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La actividad cambiara de PENDIENTE a EN PROCESO ");
             tabla2 abrir = new tabla2();
             abrir.setVisible(true);
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La actividad seguira PENDIENTE");
        }
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu problema de no poder pasar los datos de un sitio a otro se debe a que efectivamente estás realizando `rs = ps.executeQuery();` y esto guarda en el result set el resultado de la consulta de la base de datos en forma de "objeto", este "objeto" (o sea el ResultSet) debes recorrerlo para poder extraer de él los resultados de la consulta. En tu caso yo lo haría así:

```
while (rs.next()) {
  int id_act = rs.getInt("Lname");
  String nombre_actividad = rs.getString("nombre_actividad");
  String situacion ) rs.getString("situacion");
}
```

De esta manera puedes obtener para una variable el valor de cada fila obtenido en cada iteración del bucle while en el "objeto" resultset. Y ya si deseas puedes manejarlo guardarlo en un array para luego usarlo o en tu caso pasarlo a otra fila.
De todas maneras si quieres ver una página donde lo explica puedes visitar [esta](https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/jdbc/jdbc0003/) donde hay unos pequeños ejemplos.

Comment: Lo solucione, ya pasa la fila, mientras la borra de la otra tabla. solo que sigue son guardarla.